# How to remove files from a botched uninstall?

Tags: wine, uninstall

I installed wine and cheatengine at some point, and the software didn't work, so I went the bad route of just searching for the related files and deleting them. This has left a few wine and cheatengine related icons in the app list, and I can't figure out how to remove them. How can I fix a botched uninstall?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to remove the icons by going to "~/.local/share" and finding anything related to the deleted programs, and removing the files.